# selecting table which includes nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table (tbl)

[image]

I want to return these results

[image]

where Col3 is 1 if all entries (Col2) in Col1 grouping are filled, and 0 otherwise.

Is there any simple way to do this without creating any additional nested tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `case`:

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2,
       (case when count(*) = count(col2) then 1 else 0 end) as col3
from t
group by col1;
```

If you want to be inscrutable, you can do it without the `case`:

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2,
       (1 - sign(count(*) - count(col2))) as col3
from t
group by col1;
```